# How to check whether a given column in a 2D array contains all specific numbers from 0 to n?

Tags: javascript

I am having problem to search specific element in column of my 2D array. If I pass argument 2 in  check(arr,2) then I return false but when I pass 3 as argument in testArray(arr,3) then get true in console but its wrong because in column 3 there is not element 2 contain in 3rd column.Note: 2nd argument in testArray(arr,2) is represent column from 0 to 3.Can anyone help me please?

Comment: you just want to check if the given number is inside the 2D array at any position?

Comment: check's second loop doesn't loop because it returns the first result.

Comment: @QuentinUK Yes, I stuck in second loop its only return first result. Can u help me please?

Comment: for (var i = 1; i <= c.length; i++) {
    if( !arraySearch(c, i)) return false;
  } return true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second loop you returned too early! Any `true` result from an `arraySearch()`-call triggered a positive result to be returned. I changed it such, that the loop is only left prematurely, if `arraySearch()` returned `false`, otherwise it will run through all numbers and will return `true` in the end.

You can do the whole thing in a one-liner:

```js
var arr = [  [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1], [2, 3, 4, 2], [4, 1, 2, 3]];
// changed data:                                   ^

const chk=(arr,c)=>arr.map((e)=>e[c]).sort().every((e,i)=>e==(i+1))

console.log(chk(arr,2)); // false
console.log(chk(arr,3)); // true
```

Admittedly, a bit cryptic, but for someone who "loves coding" it might be an interesting challenge to work out. ;-)

First I

- extract the column in question with `.map()`
- I then `sort()` the elements and finally
- compare `every()` one of them with their index in the extracted and sorted 1D-array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ra = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1], [2, 3, 4, 1], [4, 1, 2, 3]];
const arraySearch = (r, targetNum, targetColumn) => r.map(v => v[targetColumn]).some(x => x === targetNum);
console.log(arraySearch(ra, 2, 2))
console.log(arraySearch(ra, 2, 3))
```